# Web Scraping XHR Dynamic pages with rvest and R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape a Dynamic website Morningstar.com via XHR requests.

The exact site I am scraping is: http://performance.morningstar.com/funds/etf/total-returns.action?t=SPY&region=USA&culture=en_US

What I am trying to scrape is the Quarterly performance number (1-month).  The result should be 0.64 as of today.

```
try(res <- GET(url = "http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/performance-return.action",
                 query = list(
                   t="SPY",
                   region="usa",
                   culture="en-US"
                 )
  ))

  tryCatch(x <- content(res) %>%
             html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="tab-quar-end-content"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]') %>% 
             html_text() %>%
             trimws() %>% 
             as.numeric()
           , error = function(e) x <-NA)
```

However, the result is numeric(0)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Sody

**Update:**

I was able to get the html data with the following code:

```
 try(res <- GET(url = "http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/performance-return.action",
                 query = list(

                   t = "SPY",
                   region = "usa",
                   culture = "en-US",
                   ops = "clear",
                   s = "0P0000J533",
                   ndec = "2",
                   ep = "true",
                   align = "q",
                   annlz = "true",
                   comparisonRemove = "false"

                 )
  ))
```

But I am still having problems pointing to the data using either the CSS selector or the xpath with rvest.

What do you guys use to find those data points? is SelectorGadget still the go to?

Cheers, Aaron

Comment: You should consider updating your question vs posting answers.

Comment: Good point! New to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(httr)

GET(
  url = "http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/cef/trailing-total-returns.action", 
  add_headers(
    Referer = "http://performance.morningstar.com/funds/etf/total-returns.action?t=SPY&region=USA&culture=en_US", 
    `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest"
  ),
  query = list(
    t = "ARCX:SPY", region = "usa", culture = "en-US", 
    cur = "", ops = "clear", s = "0P00001MK8", ndec = "2", ep = "true", 
    align = "q", annlz = "true", comparisonRemove = "false", 
    benchmarkSecId = "", benchmarktype = ""
  ),
  verbose()
) -> res
```

You have to target the XHR directly.

Comment: What about the xpath?`xpath ='/*[@id="tab-quar-end-content"]/table'`

Comment: That gets you the table. You were having problems just getting to the data. The table is the easy part.

Answer (score 0):

The table is embedded using java script, not hard-coded. You won't be able to scrape this data.

Comment: Well, not with httr's GET maybe, but solutions like Rselenium exist to scrape pages that require executing javascript so it's not impossible to scrape this type of data (it's just not as easy).

Comment: I have done scrapes before from sites similar to this using XHR and devtools in chrome. I don't think Rseleniom is needed.